# Too much text for overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, layout

I have a quite complex div layout.

It works on Safari and Firefox without any problem:

[image]

But opening the page on chrome gives me the following result:

[image]

So the whole screen is divided into two big divs that are placed vertically. The one at the top with the orange dots and the other one at the bottom with the colorful divs inside.

When I add too much text to the pink div the layout starts expanding itself. 
The interesting thing is that the div is gets more text than it could show and it really works because of

```
overflow: hidden;
```

But starting at a quite high number of lines the div starts expanding itself for some reason

I was trying to reproduce the issue in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pnudax2c/). 
But I am not able to.

What else could I try to find the problem?
Or does anyone see the mistake I did?

The code I give is for the half at the bottom were the problem probably is.

HTML:

```
<div class="ThirdSectionTextArea">

      <div class="ThirdSectionTextAreaCell ThirdSectionTextAreaCell1">
      </div>
      <div class="ThirdSectionTextAreaCell ThirdSectionTextAreaCell2">
          <div class="Row Row1 uppercase">
              <div class="cell cell1">
                    SOME HEADERTEXT
              </div>
               <div class="cell cell2">
                       SOME HEADERTEXT
              </div>
              <div class="cell cell3">
                       SOME HEADERTEXT
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Row Row2">
              <div class="cell cell1">
                   <table class="layoutTable"><tr><td class="centerDiv">
                       <div class="h_line">
                       </div>
                   </td></tr></table>
              </div>
               <div class="cell cell2">
                    <table class="layoutTable"><tr><td class="centerDiv">
                       <div class="h_line">
                       </div>
                   </td></tr></table>
              </div>
               <div class="cell cell3">
                    <table class="layoutTable"><tr><td class="centerDiv">
                       <div class="h_line">
                       </div>
                   </td></tr></table>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Row Row3">
              <div class="cell cell1">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              </div>
               <div class="cell cell2">
                   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

              </div>
               <div class="cell cell3">
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ThirdSectionTextAreaCell ThirdSectionTextAreaCell3">
      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="ThirdSectionBottomLayout">
       <table class="layoutTable"><tr><td class="centerDiv">
                <img src="../img/basics/Pfeil.png" alt="Pfeil" class="ThirdSectionBottomArrow">
            </td></tr></table>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.ThirdSectionTextArea {
    width:250px;;
    height:180px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.ThirdSectionBottomLayout {
    width:100%;
    height:15%;
    background-color: chartreuse;
    position:relative;
}

.ThirdSectionBottomArrow {
    top:-0%;
    height:100%;
    width:5%;
    object-fit:scale-down;
    position: absolute;
}

.ThirdSectionTextAreaCell {
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left !important;
    height:100%;
}

.ThirdSectionTextAreaCell1{
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 20%;
}

.ThirdSectionTextAreaCell2{
    background-color: fuchsia;
    width: 60%; 
}

.ThirdSectionTextAreaCell3{
    background-color: darkorchid;
    width: 20%;  
}
.ThirdSectionTextAreaCell2 .Row {
    width:100%;
}

.ThirdSectionTextAreaCell2 .Row1 {
   background-color: burlywood;
   height:20%;
}

.ThirdSectionTextAreaCell2 .Row1 .cell{
   width:33.33%;
   height:100%;
   float:left;
   overflow: scroll;
   background-color: burlywood;
}

.ThirdSectionTextAreaCell2 .Row2 {
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    height: 3%;
}

.ThirdSectionTextAreaCell2 .Row2 .cell{
   width:33.33%;
   height:100%;
   float:left;
   overflow: scroll;
}

.ThirdSectionTextAreaCell2 .Row3 {
    background-color: deeppink;
    height:77%;
}

.ThirdSectionTextAreaCell2 .Row3 .cell{
   width:33.33%;
   height:100%;
   float:left;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you can't reproduce it on fiddle? Also, what's wrong with it specifically, is it the bigger orange block being over the rest of the graphic to the right?

Comment: I have edited my post. perhaps its now more clear what the problem is.

Comment: First thing I would try when some browsers work & other not is using some css reset before aplying your own css. For example this one: https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css